# Retrieving the access token of a OAuth2 3-legged authentication using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I would like to know how to retrieve the access token on a Spring Boot 3-legged authentication using the functionalities provided by `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`

I am able to get the access token using regular `RestTemplate` calls.

I tried to get the same access token using the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` functionalities by following the example in https://github.com/wonwoo/spring-boot-oauth2-login.

I am able to retrieve the code provided by the server, but I cannot figure out how to get the access token.

My code looks like this:

Properties in `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.client-id=__client_id_here__
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.client-secret=__client_secret_here__
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.redirect-uri-template=http://localhost:8080/authentication/3leggedtoken/callback
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.scope=data:read
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.client-name=__client_name_here__
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-name-here.client-authentication-method=POST
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-client-name-here.token-uri=https://example.com/api/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-client-name-here.authorization-uri=https://example.com/api/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-client-name-here.user-info-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-client-name-here.user-name-attribute=
```

Thymeleaf template in `login.html`:

```html
<div th:each="registration: ${registrations}">
  <a th:href="@{${registration.uri}}">
      Sign in with [[${registration.clientName}]]
  </a>
</div>
```

Configuration in `SecurityConfig.java`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SegurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http_security) throws Exception {
        http_security.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/authentication/login").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Controllers in `AuthenticationController.java`:

```java
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @GetMapping("authentication/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        List<Registration> registrations = StreamSupport.stream(clientRegistrationRepository.spliterator(), true)
                .map(clientRegistration -> new Registration(clientRegistration.getRegistrationId(),
                        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI + "/"
                                + clientRegistration.getRegistrationId(),
                        clientRegistration.getClientName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        model.addAttribute("registrations", registrations);
        return "authentication/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("authentication/3leggedtoken/callback")
    public String accessToken(Model model, @RequestParam("code") String code) {     
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            String clientRegistrationId = oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId,
                    oauthToken.getName());
            return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The application successfully creates a link to the server's authentication page and the redirect URI is called back after login.

The code returned in the callback is correct

```java
public String accessToken(Model model, @RequestParam("code") String code) {...}
```

but the Authentication is not of type `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`

```java
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

but of type `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@ef72fdb1:
   Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true;
   Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364:
       RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: D8FFF6F20C14791E505B8B86648F7E1B;
       Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

How should I acquire the access token? and how should I access it to pass it on the following requests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `@GetMapping("authentication/3leggedtoken/callback")` endpoint and register it as a bean. Like this:

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope;

import sample.api.facebook.Facebook;

@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConfig.class);

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public Facebook facebook(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String accessToken = null;
        if (authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            String clientRegistrationId = oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            if (clientRegistrationId.equals("facebook")) {
                OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
                    clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, oauthToken.getName());
                accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

                LOG.error(accessToken);
            }
        }
        return new Facebook(accessToken);
    }

}
```

Then follow this tutorial [from one of Spring oauth2 developers](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github), it helped me to integrate getting Facebook token in my project.